# getting node-red to work with google assistant

Tags: node-red

Totally new to node-red & sensehat & this whole IoT thing.

I've followed the article on:
https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-google-action

Everything worked until the part where I have to test. Google Action encountered an error which says:
`"xxx isn't responding right now. Try again soon." (where xxx is my project name).`

Also, in the *google action* node, there is a "SSL private key file" and a "SSL certificate file" which i have no idea how to find the path for.

I've tried a guide to create the private key and cert and after everything's done, when i attempt to boot node-red, it says access denied & my node-red is unable to start up..

Edit:
It's a school proj so everythjng is local,under a normal router with Internet access (no vpn etc)

Question2:
According to this link:
https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-google-action
i just need a https web server in order for this to work right?

Comment: You haven't explained where Node-RED running. Is it accessable from the outside world?

Comment: @hardillb hi yes sorry, no it is not. It is in my local host.

Answer (score 0):

From the doc for the node:

> The node runs an Express web server to listen for Action request from
>   Google. By using a separate web server from Node Red, it allows the
>   node to listen on a different port. This allows the Action listener to
>   be exposed to the Internet without having the rest of Node Red also
>   exposed. The web server is required to run HTTPS so you will need SSL
>   certificates. Self signed certificates are OK

You will need to set up port forwarding or some other way to expose this express endpoint to the internet. The Google Assistant servers need to be able to reach this endpoint for anything to work.

Comment: hi. i've just configured my pi with ngrok and managed to make my node-red public with a temporary dns. that after, i still encountered the same error after following the docs. or am i missing something?

Comment: Which port did you expose? Node-RED should not be accessable, just the Assistant node

Comment: 1880. sorry am new and am abit lost in this. following this guide [link](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/exposing-your-local-node-js-app-to-the-world) under 'ngrok' . im slightly lost as to how i can configure jjust the node to be accessible to the internet. then what is my web server?, if not the node-red

Comment: correct me if im wrong, from what i'm getting so far is this: What im supposed to do is to create a web server, give it a domain name, secure it, then link the google nodes to that web server, then it should work... is that right?

Comment: No, you don't need a separate HTTPS server, you just need to forward the port you configured in the node (the place holder is 8081)

Comment: Okay so: open a secured tunnel on port 8081 via ngrok, link the Google nodes to that port. Did I get this right?